# Can I use hooks in a template for views?

Tags: 6, hooks

I'm still not sure how hooks work.

I want to join a table to one of my views, but I have no idea where I'm supposed to put the hook for that. Do I just stick it in the template for the view? Or where does it go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API reference at http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal has all of the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) hook in it: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--docs.php/group/views_hooks/6

That said, the views documentation is a little sparse.  The best thing to do is look through the list of hooks, then search on the various hook names for examples.

I suspect you need to use [hook_views_query_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--docs.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/6) but I don't think I have ever had to add a JOIN to a view before.

EDIT:

Notice another of your questions: [Join a custom table on a View](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12645/join-a-custom-table-on-a-view).

In your case, if you want to properly make a custom table Views aware, implementing [hook_views_data](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--docs.php/function/hook_views_data/6) is the correct solution.  But you still need to do this in a custom module, and not in your theme files.

Comment: Where does the hook go though? Do I have to create a new module for it, can it go in a template file?

Comment: Sorry, hooks always go in modules.