# Join a custom table on a View

Tags: views, 6

I need to join a custom table `custom_table` on a View `my_view`.

I have a module created called `join_table`

The `nid` is the referential id (the nid is what ties the two table to the view).

Then, I need to take the info the column `price` in `custom_table` and be able to display using my Views template.

I'm completely lost.

Comment: FYI: for Drupal 7 there are good answers to this question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36912/using-views-with-a-custom-table-schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api()
 * @file modulename.module
 */
function modulename_views_api() {
  return array('api' => 2);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_views_data()
 * @file modulename.views.inc
 */
function modulename_views_data() {
  $data['custom_table']['table']['join']['node'] = array(
    'left_field' => 'nid',
    'field' => 'nid',
  );

  $data['custom_table']['price'] = array(
    'title'  => 'Title',
    'help'   => 'Help',
    'group'  => t('Node'),
    'field'  => array('handler' => 'views_handler_field'),
    'sort'   => array('handler' => 'views_handler_sort'),
    'filter' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string'),
  );

  return $data;
}
```

Read more info in oficial manual [Describing tables to Views](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-tables)

Comment: Here's my issue with this: Where's the indication that this code needs to be placed in a .inc file? Where's the indication on how this code needs to be called through a module. These tutorials in Drupal are half-assed and not helpful at all. They cause me more consternation than anything else. That is why I am asking here, and I don't feel a "RTFM" type of response is at all appropriate.

Comment: Try http://treehouseagency.com/blog/neil-hastings/2010/01/19/views-handler-easy-way, that's a tutorial for a basic implementation of hook_views_data(), where you need to place it and so on.

Comment: ok, i added example

Comment: @xandeadx: awesome!